# Long-term backup retention list is not available

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, database-backups

If user is owner of the resource group and SQL server instance in it, he/she can configure LTR polices. However, when trying to list them in Available backups tab... nothing is there. Same applies to the DB restore when Long-term backup retention is selected.
Is anyone aware of some role or resource access that could resolve this?

p.s. Vault is not used any more.

[RESOLUTION] 'SQL Server contributor' role on the subscription level resolves it. Anyway, thanks everyone.

Comment: Hello @user27105.  It appears your question does not appear to be about programming within the scope defined in the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: @STLDeveloper Ok, I see. :( Thank you.

Comment: You may want to check out some sister StackExchange sites, such as [SuperUser](https://superuser.com) or [ServerFault](https://serverfault.com).

Comment: @STLDeveloper Thank you! I got it resolved in the meantime. Wondering if you will be deleting this post or leaving it, if it could help someone else?

Comment: I'm not sure to what exactly you're referring to me possibly deleting. The only thing I could possibly delete is my own comment, which I hadn't considered deleting.

Comment: @STLDeveloper Entire question since it might be out of the SO scope.

Comment: I don't think it's necessary to remove your question.  Besides, I can only vote that it be closed.  If you want to delete it, you have that capability - but unless it's received close votes (and it's only received one of 5 necessary to close it), if I were you I wouldn't do anything with it.

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround, you can try using PowerShell to list the LTR backups within a server:

```
# Get the list of all LTR backups in a specific Azure region 
# The backups are grouped by the logical database id.
# Within each group they are ordered by the timestamp, the earliest
# backup first.  
$ltrBackups = Get-AzureRmSqlDatabaseLongTermRetentionBackup -LocationName $server.Location 

# Get the list of LTR backups from the Azure region under 
# the named server. 
$ltrBackups = Get-AzureRmSqlDatabaseLongTermRetentionBackup -LocationName $server.Location -ServerName $serverName

# Get the LTR backups for a specific database from the Azure region under the named server 
$ltrBackups = Get-AzureRmSqlDatabaseLongTermRetentionBackup -LocationName $server.Location -ServerName $serverName -DatabaseName $dbName

# List LTR backups only from live databases (you have option to choose All/Live/Deleted)
$ltrBackups = Get-AzureRmSqlDatabaseLongTermRetentionBackup -LocationName $server.Location -DatabaseState Live

# Only list the latest LTR backup for each database 
$ltrBackups = Get-AzureRmSqlDatabaseLongTermRetentionBackup -LocationName $server.Location -ServerName $serverName -OnlyLatestPerDatabase
```

Make sure you have configured LTR backups correctly as explained [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-long-term-backup-retention-configure).